# Box for Salesforce Developers Toolkit Authorization Issue

Tags: apex, box

Is anyone out there using the new Box for Salesforce Developers Toolkit?  The documentation is pretty sketchy on how Auth works and I'm getting an error returned that the method is, "Unable to use default credentials to make a callout to box."  Any ideas?

```
    public void onAfterInsert(List<Claimant__c> newClaimants, Map<Id, Claimant__c> newClmtMap) {

       box.Toolkit boxToolkit = new box.Toolkit();

       for(Claimant__c aClaimant : newClaimants){
        String claimantFolderId = boxToolkit.createFolderforRecordId(aClaimant.Id, aClaimant.Last_Name__c + ', ' + aClaimant.First_Name__c, true);

        boxToolkit.commitChanges();

        //debug code - mf
        string clmfld = [SELECT folderId__c from Claimant__c where id =: aclaimant.id].folderId__c;
        system.debug('-->CFolderID: ' + clmfld);
    }

}//end onAfterInsert
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use this method in a trigger context, you should defined it with @future (callout=true). An Apex trigger can only execute a callout from a asynchronous method.